# extracting rows from one file based on another query file - linux

Tags: linux

I am trying to extract rows from one fileA based on fileB (that matches).

file A

```
chr gene start stop pval
1   xic  455   467 0.005
2   ABD  5667  5789 0.03
5   GHE  4556  4784 0.23
6   sdg  4568  4677 0.558
```

file B

```
ABD
GHE
```

so the output would be

```
chr gene start stop pval
2   ABD  5667  5789 0.03
5   GHE  4556  4784 0.34
```

and i try this code:

grep -f B A >> A_B.txt

PROBLEMS:
here in the example file everything runs fine, but when i try in my dataset it is giving the actual list(ABD,GHE) along with few other list (sdg)...

like

```
 chr gene start stop pval
    2   ABD  5667  5789 0.03
    5   GHE  4556  4784 0.34
    6   sdg  4568  4677 0.558
```

Suggestions:
How can i solve it...
And is it possible to integrate few codes so that i get only selected columns

Desired output:

```
        chr gene pval
        2   ABD  0.03
        5   GHE  0.34
        6   sdg  0.558
```

THanks so much
M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using awk

```
 awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$0; if(NR==1) print $0} ($1 in a) {print a[$1]}' FileA FileB > output.txt
```

if you want to select columns

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0}($2 in a) {print $1,$2,$5}' FileB FileA > output.txt
```

Comment: thanks it works,, will try it on the real dataset,,, how can i select two columns and direct to an output file..

Comment: you can use redirection operator to save it, I have edited the code to save it to output.txt

Comment: is that possible doing this with grep?